# remote model callbacks - rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm not phrasing the question correctly in the title, but heres what I'd like to do.

I have a method, like such:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   def myMethod(abc, xyz)
     #do stuff
   end
end
```

I want 5 different models in my app to call this function on their after_create callback.

It seems very anti-DRY to put a function in each of those models to call this function.

Is there a way in this model (above) that holds the method - to remotely use the callbacks of the other models?

Or can anyone suggest a different way I should be approaching something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what I would do:

Create a module:

```
module MyCallbacks

    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
        after_create :my_method
    end

    def my_method
        #do stuff
    end

end
```

And then, you just need to include this module in the models of your choice:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    include MyCallbacks
end
```

Comment: But by including this in the models of my choice - it doesn't really let me "manage" which models are being attached to. I.e. wouldn't I really want to specify all the models its getting the callbacks from in one place, rather than 5 separate places?

Comment: I dont think it's a problem to have to include the module in your models. At least it's explicit in each model that they have these callbacks.

Comment: If you really wanted to, I guess you could have an initializer that would include the module in your models: `YourModel.class_eval { include MyCallbacks }` (repeated for each of your models)

Comment: Interesting - it seems like there just isn't an easy way to manage it the way I had hoped - will mark this correct within the next day unless another answer comes along